# Let $X$ be positive definite, any connection between the eigenvalues of $X$ and the eigenvalues of $\Sigma X \Sigma$, $\Sigma$ is positive diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $X$ be a positive definite matrix in $\Bbb R^{n\times n}$ or $\Bbb C^{n\times n}$, is there any known connection between the eigenvalues of $X$ and the eigenvalues of $\Sigma X \Sigma$, where $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix with all diagonal elements being positive real numbers?

Comment: If $X$ is diagonal, it seems like the diagonal entries of $\Sigma X \Sigma$ can be (fill in the sentence...)

Comment: is there any connection between the coefficients of $\Sigma^2$ and 1?

Comment: @fonfonx Thanks for comment. $Sigma$ is a general diagonal matrix. Only restriction is that all its elements are positive.

Comment: @RalphB. this is why I think there is no connection between the eigenvalues of $X$ and the ones of $\Sigma X \Sigma$: for exemple take for $X$ the identity matrix: its eigenvalues are $1$. The eigenvalues of $\Sigma X \Sigma = \Sigma^2$ are the squares of the coefficients of $\Sigma$, which can take all positive values

Comment: @fonfonx Got it! Many thanks!